# removing the central white circle?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geometry

I have a circular plot and I would like to find a way to remove the little white circle in the middle.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(d5)+geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=xyz))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=NULL,limits=c(0,3.6))+
   scale_fill_continuous(low="darkgreen", high="white")+
   coord_polar(start=-1*pi/2, direction=1)+
   theme_bw()+
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

many thanks.

Comment: What is `d5`? use `dput(d5)`

Answer (score 2):

I made a dummy example here:

```
require(dplyr)
expand.grid(x = 1:20, y = 1:2) %>% 
  mutate(z = rnorm(length(x))) %>% 
  ggplot()+geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=NULL,limits=c(0,3.6))+
  scale_fill_continuous(low="darkgreen", high="white")+
  coord_polar(start=-1*pi/2, direction=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

You're on the right track with the `limits` and `expand` arguments of `scale_y`, you just need to figure out where the actual lower bound is. To do that, let's plot the same set without `coord_polar` and without your `scale_y`.

[image]

So in my example, the minimum edge of the tile is at `y=0.5`. So you have to figure out what your smallest `y` value is, and then subtract half of the default `height` for `geom_tile` (which is 1). Use that value for the lower `y` limit, and the hole in your pie will disappear.

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask about the way to set the limits of the scale on the write as "Z" is not fixed. It might be data of (died or survived). The plots of both needs to be on the same scale to make them comparable.

Comment: @HamzaMezo, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235580/how-to-get-multiple-ggplot2-scale-fill-gradientn-with-same-scale  You just need to set the same `limits=` for all the plots inside `scale_fill`.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to the answer given by @Brian.
 The correct limits of the y-axis that eliminate the little white circle in the middle can be calculated as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(4321)
d5 <- expand.grid(x = 1:20, y = 1:2) %>% 
  mutate(z = rnorm(length(x))) 

yval <- sort(unique(d5$y))
h <- (yval[2] - yval[1])/2
ylim_lo <- yval[1] - h
ylim_up <- yval[2] + h

ggplot(d5)+geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=NULL, limits=c(ylim_lo,ylim_up)) +
   scale_fill_continuous(low="darkgreen", high="white") +
   coord_polar(start=-1*pi/2, direction=1) +
   theme_bw()+
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. please till me how to upvote ?

Comment: I would like to ask about the way to set the limits of the scale on the write as "Z" is not fixed. It might be data of (died or survived). The plots of both needs to be on the same scale to make them comparable.

Comment: @HamzaMezo Please, post a clear question on SO. The SO community will be happy to help you !